# Firebug style inspect element on iPhone?

Tags: iphone

Is there anyway to do a Firebug style 'inspect element' on an iPhone?

My site works fine with Safari on my Mac but has a layout issue on iPhone.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the site using Safari on your Mac?

Answer (score 1):

They all say this is a remote debugger: http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/

From docs:

> **weinre** is a debugger for web pages, like FireBug (for FireFox) and Web Inspector (for WebKit-based browsers), except it's designed to work remotely, and in particular, to allow you debug web pages on a mobile device such as a phone.

EDIT: Here are more details and step-by-step instructions: http://envyandroid.com/archives/483/easily-debug-mobile-websites-with-weinre

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Can you add some details to this answer? How is this installed and used, and what makes it a good solution? Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Comment: @NathanGreenstein - is your comment just a copy&paste template?